# Running make on makehuman results in the following fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

Tags: 13.04, python

I have ubuntu 13.04 installed on my machine and have python-dev and python3.3-dev both installed.

I downloaded MakeHuman v1.0 alpha 7 which requires to make the package. When running `make` I encounter the following error:

```
~/Programs/makehuman$ make
compiling C file src/core.c to src/core.o ...
src/core.c:35:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [src/core.o] Error 1
```

As requested, I checked if Python.h exists:

```
~/Programs/makehuman$ ls -l /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4329 Apr 19 21:20 /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h
```

Anything I might have missed?

Comment: Interesting. `Python.h` should really be there if you have `python-dev` installed. Could you verify this and show the output of `ls -l /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h` in your question? You don't need any Python 3 here, as Makehuman seems to be only 2.7 compatible.

Comment: By the way, why are you not installing the `.deb` package rather than compiling from source? It's here: http://www.makehuman.org/content/download_alpha_7.html

Comment: Added the output. Re compiling from source, I merely was ignorant of the fact I could do so. Though, I have no idea as how I can do that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the `Makefile.Linux` file is preconfigured for use with Python 2.6 only (you don't want that on Ubuntu).

You could try to change that setting. Edit at line 8

```
PYTHONVER     = 2.6
```

to become

```
PYTHONVER     = 2.7
```

Then it will run. However, you may run into a lot more build dependencies! :)

On Ubuntu 12.04 I'm not able to compile this due to programming errors in the code. (lots of `undefined reference to`)

It will be a lot easier if you just install the `.deb` package from [the download page](http://www.makehuman.org/content/download_alpha_7.html).

Comment: I have change the version though encountered with the same error. I tried to install the dev package but says I require libglew which is installed, though i better reserve that for another question

Comment: @Drahcir You'll need `libglew1.6-dev` for `GL/glew.h` and `libglew1.6` at runtime. But then you will encounter programming errors for compiling this source. :( Maybe you can try a specific GCC release or something, but the docs don't mention anything about the build instructions for Linux.

Comment: Hmm ye, can't really blame them since it is alpha. I tried to install the previos version from the ubuntu store though the button gui locations don't seem to match to match their physical locations.

It's a shame since it looks very promising bit of kit